# Moving files and folders between different versions of Sharepoint

Tags: export

My office needs to move files between 2 versions of sharepoint. Currently Sharepoint 2003 is being used and the files from here need to be moved to Sharepoint 3.0. Also the 2 sharepoint editions are on different servers.

Is there any way to export/import other than manually uploading files to the new sharepoint? What would be the way to export?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you can - try opening the documents library of SPS 2003 and MOSS 2007 in explorer view. keep them side by side and drag and drop folders from 2003 to 2007.

Answer (score 1):

STSADM is your best friend for this and most other things! check these links that should help you out!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272630/how-to-move-documents-from-sharepoint-2003-to-sharepoint-2007-with-versioning

and

http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/exportimport-moss-document-library-5516.aspx

in greater detail:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/10/stsadm-export-content-deployment.html

and

http://blogs.technet.com/b/edwalt/archive/2008/07/25/3093877.aspx

I hope its what your looking for :)